# Application problem after build - ElectronJS

Tags: node.js, build, path, electron, electron-packager

I've build my electronJS application with electron-packager and after the build finished, when I launched it, every data was gone. And I got an error that I've never got before on the dev app. (C.F screenshot)
paths are right because it's working on my dev app with the same configuration.
How can I fix this quickly please.
[image: a busy cat]

I've tried to change the directory to full path, change inside of the config.js file.

C.F : https://imgur.com/gallery/VN17hNf

Get all my data and my application work correctly. (get all data, add data, display data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem. When you build your app, you need to use relative paths. Like `path.join(xxx)`. The app doesn't understand the `./your_path`.
And next problem that I've solved, if you use json file and write data inside of it, you need to have a unpacked app w/ .asar file.